# Multiple parameter optimization with a stochastic element

Tags: algorithm, optimization, random

I am looking for a method to find the best parameters for a simulation. It's about break-shots in billiards / pool. A shot is defined by 7 parameters, I can simulate the shot and then rate the outcome and I would like to compute the best parameters.

I have found the following link here:
[Multiple parameter optimization with lots of local minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900577/multiple-parameter-optimization-with-lots-of-local-minima)
suggesting 4 kinds of algorithms. In the pool simulator I am using, **the shots are altered by a little random value** each time it is simulated. If I simulate the same shot twice, the outcome will be different. So I am looking for an algorithm like the ones in the link above, only with the addition of a stochastical element, optimizing for the 7 parameters that will on average yield the best parameters, i.e. a break shot that most likely will be a success. My initial idea was simulating the shot 100 or 1000 times and just take the average as rating for the algorithms above, but I still feel like there is a better way. Does anyone have an idea?

The 7 parameters are continuous but within different ranges (one from 0 to 10, another from 0.0 to 0.028575 and so on).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for some of the algorithms, simulating the *same* shot repeatedly might not be neccessary. As long as your alternatives have some form of momentum, like in the swarm simulation approach, you can let that be affected by the outcome of each individual simulation. In that case, a single unlucky simulation would slow the movement in parameter space only slightly, whereas a serious loss of quality should be enough to stop and reverse the movement. Thos algorithms which don't use momentum might be tweaked to have momentum. If not, then repeated simulation seems the best approach. Unless you can get your hands on the internals of the simulator, and rate the shot as a whole without having to simulate it over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the algorithms you mentioned in your non-deterministic scenario with independent stochastic runs. Your idea with repeated simulations is good, you can read more about [how many repeats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination) you might have to consider for your simulations (unfortunately, there is no trivial answer). If you are not so much into maths, and the runs go fast, do 1.000 repeats, then 10.000 repeats, and see if the results differ largely. If yes, you have to collect more samples, if not, you are probably on the safe side (the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) states that the results converge).

Further, **do not just consider the average**! Make sure to look into the standard deviation for each algorithm's results; you might want to use [box plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) to compare their quartiles. If you rely on the average only, you could pick an algorithm that produces very varying results, sometimes excellent, sometimes terrible in performance.

I don't know what language you are using, but if you use Java, I am maintaining [a tool](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT) that could simplify your "monte carlo" style experiments.